# Geodesic surfaces in manifolds, what are they called, and do they exist?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold $M$ (or any manifold with enough structure to talk about geodesics).

> **Definition.** Let a *geodesic surface* $X\subseteq M$ be submanifold, so that any geodesic in $M$ through a point $p\in X$ and with direction $v\in T_p X$ lies completely in $X$.

For me, this feels like some kind of higher dimensional geodesic in $M$.
For example, affine subspaces in $\Bbb R^n$, or great-spheres in $\Bbb S^n$ are geodesic surfaces.

> **Quesion:** Is there a standard name for such submanifold, and what can be said about their existence?

For example, if I am given a point $p\in M$ and a direction $v\in T_p M$, there is a (maximal) geodesic $\gamma_{p,v}$ through $p$ with direction $v$.
Equivalently, for linearly independent $v_1,...,v_k\in T_p M$ I could ask for the existence of such a (maximal) geodesic surface $X_{v_1,...,v_k}$ of dimension $k$ and containing all $\gamma_{p,v_i}$. *Do these surfaces always exist?*

Naively, I would probably set $X_{v_1,...,v_k}\subseteq M$ to be the union of all geodesic $\gamma_{p,v}$ with $v\in\mathrm{span}\{v_1,...,v_k\}\subseteq T_p M$.
Any geodesic surface must contain the $\gamma_{p,v}$, so this is a good start, but I am far from proving that any geodesics of $M$ that does not pass through $p$ is also contained in this set.

Comment: A [totally geodesic submanifold](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Totally_geodesic_submanifold) $X$ of $(M, g)$ is a submanifold for which every geodesic on $X$ is also a geodesic on $M$. This isn't exactly what you are asking about, but may be of interest to you.

Comment: Something that is very close to what you're asking for is geodesic convexity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_convexity

Comment: To the second point of your question: there is a notion of totally geodesic flat submanifolds with maximal dimension, so called flats, in the theory of symmetric spaces $S$. These flats correspond to certain maximal abelian subalgebras of the lie algebra generated by the group of isometries acting on $S$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Actually, this class is exactly the one of totally geodesic submanifolds (this follows from the uniqueness theorem for geodesics with the given initial position and velocity).

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Good point. I completely missed that.